# Silhouette Studio 4.4. not showing text

Tags: graphics, design

I installed silhouette studio 4.4 but when I opened it the panels just show icons but no text. I installed 4.2 but still the same issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where did you obtain this software? How did you install it? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I downloaded from https://www.silhouetteamerica.com/software. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, I install it using wine

Comment: So if there is no Linux client for this software, you'll need to determine whether or not it can be emulated on Ubuntu, and how well it might run.  Wine is not a panacea. Any Windows app you attempt to run will have its own quirks you need to research how to overcome. Silhouette Studio has a ["garbage" rating on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16375). I would not expect it to be usable. You could probably run this software in a VM running Windows. Otherwise, you'll need to install Windows in dual-boot config or simply use other software.

Comment: Version 4.4.455 is rated "silver" however this is based on a rating from a single test result from a single individual where there are no installation notes, no instructions, no "how to", and if you read the test notes it says *"The most important core function wasn't tested: Cutting. Simply because the software does not recognize the plotter"* - Unfortunately you probably aren't going to be able to use this software on Ubuntu. There are 0 contributors on WineHQ that are involved with figuring out how to run this software over Wine.